# Is there a way to retrieve the file's version and description name like how Control Panel (Programs and Features) did in python?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to write a script to extract a file's version and description name like what they did on the Control Panel (Programs and Features)

I've tried using some Python libraries such as win32com.client and Dispatch to get the result. They can only work on some file, such as Google Chrome.exe.

## getting file's version

```
    def get_version(filename):
        parser = Dispatch("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        version = parser.GetFileVersion(filename)
        return version
```

## getting file's description name

```
     def get_description(filename):
        sh=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Shell.Application',0)
        file = Path(filename)
    ...
         if fdExist == 1:
            for colnum in range(len(columns)):
                colval=ns.GetDetailsOf(item, colnum)
                if colval:
                    if str(columns[colnum]) == 'File description':
                        return (str(colval))
```

The program is able to output:
        Description Name: Google Chrome
        , Version Number: 74.0.3729.157

If I point the path to chrome.exe but if I point it to SQLiteStudio, it will output:
        Description Name: SQLiteStudio
        , Version Number:

I understand that in SQLiteStudio, "Properties>Details", the version was empty. However, in Control Panel (Programs and Features), they managed to display the version.

I want to know if there's anyway to retrieve the version number?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` in registry may be worth a look.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Hi! Thank you for your reply! I've looked into the registry, however,  inside the Uninstall folder, it did not contain some of the programs that are reflected on the Control Panel (Programs and Features). Is there any other way to retrieve the data from the Control Panel (Programs and Features)? Thank you!